# The type 'ReactiveUI.ReactiveObject' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced

Tags: c#, .net, reactiveui, caliburn.micro.reactiveui

> ***Error  8   The type 'ReactiveUI.ReactiveObject' is defined in an assembly
>   that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
>   'ReactiveUI, Version=6.0.3.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'. D:\git\ProjectName\ViewModels\AboutViewModel.cs 15  25  JIMS***

I have hard time resolving this issue from the past few hours. I have replaced `Caliburn.Micro` with `Caliburn.Micro.ReactiveUI`. I referenced this dll using nuget, initially there was a signing issue, but resolved that by modifying my MSBuild script to sign this assembly.

Now I am receive this error, even though I have a referenced added to this assembly. I have looked to the other realted SO questions, but nothing helped.

Things tried so far

> 1. Uninstalled Caliburn.Micro.ReactiveUI package with dep using Nuget and
>      reinstalled.
> 2. Cleaned the solution and rebuild.
> 3. Changed build from Debug to Release, nothing worked.

***Update***

Further digging into the issue, this is what I have noticed.
I un-installed the all package using

```
PM> Uninstall-Package Caliburn.Micro.ReactiveUI -RemoveDependencies
```

and then I reinstalled, now I checked ReactiveUI.dll using dotPeek, and this is what it has

```
ReactiveUI, Version=6.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
```

and the assembly is not signed yet and has `StrongName=False`
Now when I build the project, which will sign the unsinged dll as part of MSBuild script

```
<Target Name="SignAssembly" Outputs="%(Reference.HintPath)" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">
  <ConvertToAbsolutePath Paths="%(Reference.HintPath)">
    <Output TaskParameter="AbsolutePaths" PropertyName="AssemblyPath" />
  </ConvertToAbsolutePath>
  <Message Text="Assembly Path: $(AssemblyPath)" />    
  <Exec Command="&quot;$(SignerPath)\$(Signer)&quot; -a &quot;$(AssemblyPath)&quot; &gt; &quot;$(OutputLogFile)&quot;" IgnoreExitCode="true" />
  <ReadLinesFromFile File="$(OutputLogFile)">
    <Output TaskParameter="Lines" ItemName="OutputLogFile" />
  </ReadLinesFromFile>
  <Message Text="@(OutputLogFile->'%(Identity)', '%0a%0d')" />
  <Delete Files="$(OutputLogFile)" />
</Target>
```

Excuse me, creating the log file and deleting is just for debugging.
Now I again checked the assembly info from dotPeek and this is what it shows after signing the dll

```
ReactiveUI, Version=6.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=831a72fa0d8caa87
```

Now I get a little idea about what's going wrong, so once the assembly is signed, it is a different assembly for MSBuild.

So how would I update the reference to the new signed dll, in Visual Studio

Comment: Is it possible to check this project or a similar one that reproduces this issue?

Comment: The issue is because Caliburn.Micro.ReactiveUI internally reference the non signed ReactiveUI.dll, when I sign it, it becomes a different assembly for Caliburn.Micro.ReactiveUI, in order to make it work, I have to rebuild Caliburn.Micro.ReactiveUI will the signed dll

Comment: Oh OK. Feel free to do so, as I don't plan on providing a signed version (nor is Paul doing one of ReactiveUI any time soon afaik).

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the packages for ReactiveUI and Caliburn.Micro? Judging by what you are saying, you've only added Caliburn.Micro.ReactiveUI that only references the core libraries for both frameworks.

Comment: Package for Caliburn.Micro already exists, since it works on top of Caliburn.MIcro

Comment: Did you manually add ReactiveUI as well? Caliburn.Micro.ReactiveUI only reference reactiveui-core. Can you post the content of your packages.config file?